# setting self of UIView background color

Tags: objective-c, uiview

i'm trying to do this from inside the .m of a custom view class that is *not* being loaded from the XIB, but rather programmatically:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code

    self.backgroundColor=[UIColor redcolor];
}
return self;
}
```

i have the same result whether i put the background color in the initWithFrame or other methods. the background color property doesn't take. from the controller, which owns this custom view, i can set the background color fine, with:

```
self.mycustomview.backgroundColor=[UIColor redcolor];
```

But I'd like to do this from within the custom view itself, keep stuff like this independent. both the controller and the custom view import UIKit.

I also tried this, which was available from Code Sense:

```
    self.View.backgroundColor=[UIColor redcolor];
```

but that doesn't work either. i tried both `view` and `View` here. I'm sure I'm overlooking something very obvious.

in the view controller i have this, and it works fine. the custom view is called "mapButtons.h":

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
CGRect frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
self.mapButtons=[[mapButtons alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
self.mapButtons.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

[self.view addSubview:self.mapButtons];
```

the .h of the custom view is this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface mapButtons : UIView
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I compile" request for member backgroundcolor is something not a structure or union"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested again and this is the full source for what I am doing that works

```
// MapButtons.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

// As a note you normally define class names starting with a capital letter
// but I did test this with mapButtons as you had it
@interface MapButtons : UIView

@end

// MapButtons.m
#import "mapButtons.h"

@implementation mapButtons

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
      // Initialization code
      self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    return self;
}

@end

// TestAppDelegate.m
@implementation TestAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{  
    MapButtons *view = [[MapButtons alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [self.window addSubview:view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The fact that xcode is not auto completing is odd but I seem to have this issue intermittently so I have no real solution. People sometimes suggest deleting the projects derived data and restarting xcode.

Comment: hmm.. there must be something else going on. XCode doesn't even complete the "backgroundcolor" as I type it; though it will do this in the view controller that owns this. what are you importing at the top of the MyView.h/m?

Comment: Is your custom view extending `UIView`? e.g. `@interface MyView : UIView`

Comment: Yes, it is extending UIView and indeed I can change backgroundcolor on it from the controller, but not from within the view itself. very weird.

Comment: That suggests to me that you have an instance of `UIView` as your view and not your custom subclass because you are not calling it properly. Can we see where you instantiate your custom view

Comment: i've added that to my answer... however I think there is something more fundamental going on, as why would XCode not even let me autocomplete the typing of "self.backgroundcolor" inside the view but lets me autocomplete it in the controller? Whenever XCode doesn't offer autocomplete it usually means that you are trying to do something that is not available.

Comment: you are not going to believe this.. or maybe you will. I closed XCode completely and re-opened. Dot notation for backgroundcolor is now available and it all works without error! it was an XCode issue. what a relief. i was unable to even access `self.subviews` i noticed too. now it's all good.

Answer (score 5):

If your view is getting created from a XIB (i.e. you added it to some other view using Interface Builder), `-initWithFrame:` is not going to get called. An object being loaded from a XIB receives `-initWithCoder:` instead. Try this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];

    if(self)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: thanks but I am adding the view programmatically, no XIB involved. i'll update the question to reflect this.