# Change background color of custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicolor

I want to change background color of my custom `UIView`. I'm writing background color code inside `init` function but nothing happens. I think It is because `UIView's` frame hasn't been set when I declare background color. However, I don't know how can I solve it.

**My Custom Class Code**

```
class WelcomeScreenButtonView: UIView {

private lazy var label = UILabel()
private lazy var logoImage = UIImageView()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    setupUI()
    setupConstraints()
}
public convenience init(text: String, imageName: String){
    self.init()
    self.label.text = text
    self.logoImage.image = UIImage(named: imageName)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
}
required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupConstraints(){
    logoImage.anchor(self.topAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
    label.anchor(self.logoImage.bottomAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 10, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
}
func setupUI(){
    layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
    logoImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    logoImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    logoImage.tintColor = UIColor.white
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.numberOfLines = 2
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.font = GeneralFont.lightFont.withSize(13)

    addSubview(label)
    addSubview(logoImage)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

}
}
```

I also tried to do it where I declare this custom view

```
let myCustomView = WelcomeScreenButtonView()
myCustomView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

But nothing happened. Btw, I'm putting this View inside `UIStackView`.

**EDIT:** As your answers, I think I have problem where I declare it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let incidentView = WelcomeScreenButtonView(text: "Hasar\nAnında", imageName: "hasar")
    stackView.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
    stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.fillProportionally
    stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.bottom
    stackView.spacing = 0.0
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(incidentView)
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.anchor(nil, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: self.view.bottomAnchor, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 90, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 90)

}
```

P.S: I checked lots of posts about this problem but most of them are for Xib views and in objective-c. Therefore, I wanted to ask as a new question.

Posts I checked;

[setting self of UIView background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084689/setting-self-of-uiview-background-color)

[Setting background color of UIView subclass doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660480/setting-background-color-of-uiview-subclass-doesnt-work)

Comment: AFAIK `frame` does not interfere with `backgroundColor`.. what do you observe with the view? has it white background, clear background, or what's going on? Are you sure that the view has non-zero size? That its `alpha` is `> 0`?

Comment: Are logo image and label shown? I think if you change image and logo's background color to clear color then changed background color shown

Comment: I can change background colors of items (label, imageView etc) but can't change the whole view.

Comment: @EmreÖnder, It is working

Comment: How? :) @RAJAMOHAN-S

Comment: What about frame for your new object? ..i.e.,`let myCustomView = WelcomeScreenButtonView(frame: self.view.frame)`

Comment: I'm putting it inside UIStackView and give anchors to that stackview.  I think there will be problem about it.

Comment: There should not be a problem setting `backgroundColor` in the `init`, check the frame of your view or look for subviews possibly covering the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your code  your have to set Stack like that so that custom-view have stack-frame

```
       stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.fill
        stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.fill
```

viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let incidentView = WelcomeScreenButtonView(text: "Hasar\nAnında", imageName: "hasar")
         stackView.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
            stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.fill
            stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.fill
            stackView.spacing = 0.0
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(incidentView)
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.anchor(nil, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: self.view.bottomAnchor, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 90, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 90)

}
```

Comment: Now I can give background color inside viewDidLoad. I'll mark it as a working solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually the problem is that your are setting background color in `init()`.

`init` actually used to initialise view/object (i.e. memory is allocated to view/object)

But you was setting color in `init()` it means that view memory is not get allocated.

Thats the reason background color is not get set on view.

you need to set it after view is successfully initialised.

```
let view = MyCustomView()
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: So It is because Views frame hasn't been set in init function?

Comment: There are several designated initialiser are available, that you can use for various purpose.

Comment: Actually my problem is that when I put customView inside StackView, I want stack view distribution to bottom but when I do like that, I can't set background color. I think there should be a more clever way of doing this.

Comment: try to set. the frame of view at the time of initialisation. It might possible that view is initialised but the from is zero in that case background color is not visible.

Answer (score 2):

Try by putting in in draw method

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
}
```

Comment: I put it and put background color code inside it but nothing happened.

Comment: Try by setting in this method required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

Comment: call setupUI from it

Comment: set background color in this method required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}